# Xcode 8.2.1 crash when click on .storyboard file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Xcode 8.2.1 crash when clicked on Main.Storyboard.
I am trying these

--> Create new project and open Min.storyboard also crashed.

--> Right click on the file .xcworkspace > Show Package Contents
    Delete the xcuserdata folder.

--> Clean project.

--> Restart xcode

--> Restart mac.

```
Process:               Xcode [4780]
Path:                  
/Users/USER/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.2.1 (11766.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11766001000000000~5
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4780]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-05-24 13:16:11.476 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        2B27E656-FF06-3C25-BD1E-3F5697C8D4CD


Time Awake Since Boot: 6900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue:                 
IB.ExecutionQueue.IBCocoaTouchToolManager

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8C1002
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSDate hasSuffix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f83ebc32100
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
3   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
4   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
6   __82-[IBAbstractPlatformToolExecutionContext populateEnvironment:launchContext:error:]_block_invoke_3 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
7   ____NSDictionaryEnumerate_block_invoke.431 (in CoreFoundation)
8   CFBasicHashApply (in CoreFoundation)
9   __NSDictionaryEnumerate (in CoreFoundation)
10   __82-[IBAbstractPlatformToolExecutionContext populateEnvironment:launchContext:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
11   __82-[IBAbstractPlatformToolExecutionContext populateEnvironment:launchContext:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
12   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
13   dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
14   -[IBAbstractPlatformToolExecutionContext populateEnvironment:launchContext:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
15  0x0000000121bf2e42 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
16  0x0000000121c2ed0b (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
17   -[IBAbstractPlatformToolExecutionContext environmentWithLaunchContext:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
18  0x0000000121c2dbdc (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
19   +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
20   -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager launchNewToolWithDescription:error:forReason:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
21  0x0000000121b2ea4a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
22   -[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager cachedToolWithDescription:error:forReason:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
23  0x0000000121b2e8e1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
24  0x0000000121b05a1a (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
25   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
26   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
27   DVTDispatchSync (in DVTFoundation)
28   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
29  0x0000000121b057e7 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
30   -[IBDocument preflightUnarchivingDocumentHandlingOrReturningError:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
31   -[IBDocument unarchivePlatformIndependentDataWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
32   -[IBStoryboardDocument unarchivePlatformIndependentDataWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
33   -[IBDocument unarchiveDocumentWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
34   __48-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
35   -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
36   -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
37   __61-[IBDocument decodeContentsOfURL:ofType:decodingStyle:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
38   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager ignoreAutolayoutStatusInvalidationDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
39   -[IBDocument ignoreAutolayoutStatusInvalidationDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
40   -[IBDocument decodeContentsOfURL:ofType:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
41   -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
42   -[NSDocument _initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
43   -[NSDocument initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
44   -[IDEEditorDocument initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEKit)
45   -[IBDocument initForURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
46   +[IDEDocumentController _newEditorDocumentWithClass:forURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:extension:error:] (in IDEKit)
47   -[IDEEditorContext _newEditorDocumentWithClass:forURL:withContentsOfURL:ofType:extension:error:] (in IDEKit)
48   -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:documentExtension:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
49   -[IDEEditorContext _openNavigableItem:withContentsOfURL:shouldInstallEditorBlock:] (in IDEKit)
50   -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
51   -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
52   -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorOpenSpecifier:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
53   -[IDEEditorContext openEditorOpenSpecifier:] (in IDEKit)
54   -[IDEEditorModeViewController openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:] (in IDEKit)
55   -[IDEEditorArea _openEditorOpenSpecifier:editorContext:takeFocus:] (  in IDEKit)
56   __108+[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
57   +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
58   +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
59   -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] (in IDEKit)
60   __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
61   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
62   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
63   __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
64   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
65   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
66   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
67   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
68   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
69   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
70   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
71   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
72   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
73   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
74   start (in libdyld.dylib)

 abort() called

 Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: 
 IB.ExecutionQueue.IBCocoaTouchToolManager
```

Pelase help!!!

Comment: `-[__NSDate hasSuffix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.  Somewhere it's using a `NSString` method on a `NSDate` object that's why it crashes. But why, that's another question. Is your Main.storyboard corrupt? If it crashes on a new project, I'd reinstall XCode.

Comment: Do you use @IBDesignable inside your project ?

Comment: @IBDesignable  not used

Comment: @RamVinayYadav - are you split the date using suffix, is not array  so the error will throw , check once in your project

Comment: Any DatePicker on your storyboard? Did set any control value with NSDate?